# a shin of beef into beggar's purse

Tags: expressions

As part of a rather haranguing passage I came across the following expression:
"Sheer! [i.e. Scram!] or *I'll pitch into you like a shin of beef into a beggar's wallet*." the consequences of which I have difficulties to  figure. (H.Melville, White-Jacket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[**To pitch into**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/144682?redirectedFrom=pitch%20into%20#eid1262576817)" someone is a somewhat rare term meaning "**To attack or assail forcibly (with blows, words, etc.)**". So the speaker is threatening to attack someone.

As for the "shin of beef into a beggar's wallet", Melville is using a simile comparing (one assumes) the swiftness and fervor of his blows to the swiftness with which a beggar might secure a bit of meat.

Not unlike saying "I'll hit you quicker than a hungry beggar can steal meat", but with Melville's flair.

Comment: I like your interpretation, (although I wonder, why a beggar would want to put the meat in his wallet in the first place).